# asp.net mvc execute OrderProduct action from summary view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding

I have the following problem, 
I'm creating functionality for ordering products for internet shop. 
Everything works fine, user can add products to cart. This is how user can complete order:

user goes to cart (cartview)  ,
user must provide shipping details (shippingDetailsView)  ,
summary page is displayed (summaryView)  ,
sending order to server ,
displaying thank you page,

however when user click "proceed" button in summaryView (which is strongly typed by OrderViewModel class) then CompleteOrder action is executed that gets the following parameters:

```
public ViewResult CompleteOrder(ShoppingCart shoppingCart, OrderViewModel orderViewModel, string returnUrl)
```

OrderViewModel class looks as follows

```
public class OrderViewModel
    {
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

the problem is that Order object inside my orderViewModel object is null. I created some hiddenfields in my summaryView so the Order will be passed appropraite:

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Order.Client.Firstname)%>
```

However I don't think this is a good solution. How can I do it appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CompleteOrder already has the ReturnUrl parameter, why not simplify your model and just pass the Order itself:

```
public ViewResult CompleteOrder(ShoppingCart shoppingCart, Order order, string returnUrl
```